# How to auto-destroy associate for accepts_nested_attributes_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `User` with multiple `Posts`

```
class User
  has_many :posts
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :posts, allow_destroy: true
end

class Post
  belongs_to :user
end
```

In controller, I will update through

```
@user.update({ posts_attributes: [{uuid:'blah1'},{uuid:'blah2'}] })
```

I hope it can auto-destroy non-existing `posts` in every update.

```
@user.update({ posts_attributes: [{uuid:'blah1'},{uuid:'blah2'}] }) # create blah1, create blah2
@user.update({ posts_attributes: [{uuid:'blah2'},{uuid:'blah3'}] }) # delete blah1, create blah3
```

How can I achieve this?

**Update:**

I know this can be done through

```
@user.update({ posts_attributes: [{uuid:'blah1',:_destroy:true},{uuid:'blah2'},{uuid:'blah3'}] })
```

But this is not decent from my perspective. Can it be inside model instead of outside model?

**Update:**

I found this [link](https://developers.500px.com/synchronize-associations-through-nested-attributes-d95391cf1d99) but it looks much complicated.

Comment: You can pass `_destroy: true` in your params.

Comment: @MarekLipka can it be code in model so that I do not need to explicitly list `_destroy` outside model?

Comment: I would do it explicitly, since that is the way this is done in rails. Otherwise, you mnight run into issues when you would later want to update a single record, which would then risk triggering a lot of unwanted deletes.